# Floating output/making a non-self stabilizing algorithm self stabilizing

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems

So we're using this book by Shlomi Dolev on self-stabilization in class. Not being from a theretical CS background, I think the book is rather terse. Most of it is fine but there's this section on "recomputation of floating output" that I just couldn't get and I would like to know if anyone could help explain the concept in a bit more depth. There's probably a more commonly accepted term for it in the field of distributed systems, so if anyone recognizes the concept, the common name for it would be very helpful as well.

As I understand it, the gist of it is that you take a non-stabilizing, finite algorithm A and run it forever. With some care regarding tracking arguments and outputs of each iteration, you can turn algorithm A into a self-stabilizing algorithm. But that's about the limit of my understanding and again, the book doesn't do an amazing job explaining it...

Comment: It is basically the same thing as what we describe in Section 2 of this survey: https://users.ics.aalto.fi/suomela/local-self-stab/ (in particular, see Section 2.4, which tries to explain it with the help of some illustrations).

Comment: That looks like a fantastic survey, perfect for me. Thanks